# app won't install after package rename

Tags: android, eclipse, package, apk

In order to easily test some features I created a stripped down copy of my app. Unfortunately neither of the applications seem to run any more. I have changed the package name for one of them to avoid one overwriting the other and the manifests both display the correct package for their respective projects.

Here is the error in the console window ->

```
[2011-12-24 11:37:44 - AGOS - LevelTest] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=package.package.package/.MyLaunchActivity }
[2011-12-24 11:37:44 - AGOS - LevelTest] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2011-12-24 11:37:44 - AGOS - LevelTest] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {package.package.package/package.package.package.MyLaunchActivity} does not exist.
```

Does anybody know what I've forgotten to configure?

EDIT:

I found that the manifest from the newer of the two copies had a problem. During the renaming the refractor must have changed the `android:name` attribute from `MyLaunchActivity` to `package.package.package.MyLaunchActivtiy` the older one is still faulty though.

Comment: Check package name in your java files.

Comment: How did you change your package name? Used the "Rename application package" option from the ADT? Or changed things by hand?

Comment: I used the refractor in eclipse (probably a mistake =/)

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski and yes all the java files seem to be in order.

Comment: Yeah that kinda messes things up a lot, since you have to change the package in more places than eclipse is aware of *(and even if you fix it after, something is off in my experience)*. If you have a version of your code prior to the name change, revert to that. Then right click on your project and select `Android -> Rename application package`.

Comment: @alextsc Got it working now but thank you i'll keep that in mind for the future ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Turns out that the eclipse refractor renamed the `android:name` attribute in the manifest to contain the package name aswell as the launch activity. Not sure why the older version wasn't installing but it seems to be fine now ^^

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you just need to remove the original package from the device/emulator.

I've had the same problem in the past and removing my 'working' app from the emulator allowed for the renamed app to install and run properly.

Edit: more info on how to remove a package:
http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f4/how-to-uninstall-delete-an-application-from-the-emulator-126/
or 
go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications and you can uninstall it from there.

Comment: Too bad, maybe try installing to a new AVD?