# Android project rename - won't launch now

Tags: android, android-activity, launch

After successful tests I've tried to rename my project / package from, 'test...' to something more relevant. I used the various Eclipse refactor helpers where possible. All the source files appear to have the right package at the top now, the manifest seems to have the right package name, etc. I performed a 'clean'.

All seemed well. Only problem is that it won't launch - doesn't even get to the activity onCreate() handler. It crashes at AvtivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line 2417.

Clearly something still has the old name in it, but I cannot find it.

Any suggestions where to look / what to do?

As requested: log cat (nothing in console):

```
07-14 07:00:04.149: D/AndroidRuntime(347): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<br>
07-14 07:00:04.149: D/AndroidRuntime(347): CheckJNI is ON<br>
07-14 07:00:04.389: D/AndroidRuntime(347): --- registering native functions ---<br>
07-14 07:00:04.830: D/ddm-heap(347): Got feature list request<br>
07-14 07:00:05.239: D/AndroidRuntime(347): Shutting down VM<br>
07-14 07:00:05.250: D/dalvikvm(347): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to  exit<br>
07-14 07:00:05.250: D/dalvikvm(347): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down<br>
07-14 07:00:05.250: D/dalvikvm(347): HeapWorker thread shutting down<br>
07-14 07:00:05.259: D/dalvikvm(347): HeapWorker thread has shut down<br>
07-14 07:00:05.259: D/jdwp(347): JDWP shutting down net...<br>
07-14 07:00:05.269: I/dalvikvm(347): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries<br>
07-14 07:00:05.279: D/dalvikvm(347): VM cleaning up<br>
07-14 07:00:05.291: E/AndroidRuntime(347): ERROR: thread attach failed<br>
07-14 07:00:05.309: D/dalvikvm(347): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 629532 of 5242880 (12%)<br>
07-14 07:00:05.801: D/AndroidRuntime(355): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<br>
07-14 07:00:05.809: D/AndroidRuntime(355): CheckJNI is ON<br>
07-14 07:00:06.049: D/AndroidRuntime(355): --- registering native functions ---<br>
07-14 07:00:06.490: D/ddm-heap(355): Got feature list request<br>
07-14 07:00:06.910: D/ActivityManager(52): Uninstalling process uk.co.nightshadearts.golfcaddy<br>
07-14 07:00:06.910: I/ActivityManager(52): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=uk.co.nightshadearts.golfcaddy/uk.co.nightshadearts.golfcaddy }<br>
07-14 07:00:06.969: D/AndroidRuntime(355): Shutting down VM<br>
07-14 07:00:06.969: D/dalvikvm(355): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit<br>

07-14 07:00:07.009: E/AndroidRuntime(355): ERROR: thread attach failed<br>
07-14 07:00:07.009: D/dalvikvm(355): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down<br>
07-14 07:00:07.009: D/dalvikvm(355): HeapWorker thread shutting down<br>
07-14 07:00:07.019: D/dalvikvm(355): HeapWorker thread has shut down<br>
07-14 07:00:07.019: D/jdwp(355): JDWP shutting down net...<br>
07-14 07:00:07.019: I/dalvikvm(355): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries<br>
07-14 07:00:07.051: D/dalvikvm(355): VM cleaning up<br>
07-14 07:00:07.070: D/dalvikvm(355): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 639500 of 5242880 (12%)<br>
07-14 07:00:07.160: I/ActivityManager(52): Start proc uk.co.nightshadearts.golfcaddy for activity uk.co.nightshadearts.golfcaddy/uk.co.nightshadearts.golfcaddy: pid=362 uid=10031 gids={1015}<br>
07-14 07:00:07.309: D/ddm-heap(362): Got feature list request<br>
07-14 07:00:07.460: W/ActivityThread(362): Application uk.co.nightshadearts.golfcaddy is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...<br>
07-14 07:00:07.489: I/System.out(362): Sending WAIT chunk<br>
07-14 07:00:07.510: I/dalvikvm(362): Debugger is active<br>
07-14 07:00:07.750: I/System.out(362): Debugger has connected<br>
07-14 07:00:07.750: I/System.out(362): waiting for debugger to settle...<br>
07-14 07:00:07.951: I/System.out(362): waiting for debugger to settle...<br>
07-14 07:00:08.150: I/System.out(362): waiting for debugger to settle...<br>
07-14 07:00:08.350: I/System.out(362): waiting for debugger to settle...<br>
07-14 07:00:08.559: I/System.out(362): waiting for debugger to settle...<br>
07-14 07:00:08.759: I/System.out(362): waiting for debugger to settle...<br>
07-14 07:00:08.960: I/System.out(362): waiting for debugger to settle...<br>
07-14 07:00:09.187: I/System.out(362): waiting for debugger to settle...<br>
07-14 07:00:09.397: I/System.out(362): waiting for debugger to settle...<br>
07-14 07:00:09.609: I/System.out(362): waiting for debugger to settle...<br>
07-14 07:00:09.827: I/System.out(362): waiting for debugger to settle...<br>
07-14 07:00:10.039: I/System.out(362): waiting for debugger to settle...<br>
07-14 07:00:10.263: I/System.out(362): waiting for debugger to settle...<br>
07-14 07:00:10.479: I/System.out(362): debugger has settled (1449)<br>
07-14 07:00:10.681: E/gralloc(52): [unregister] handle 0x3fa718 still locked (state=40000001)<br>
07-14 07:00:17.029: W/ActivityManager(52): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!<br>
07-14 07:00:17.391: W/ActivityManager(52): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44f00a48 uk.co.nightshadearts.golfcaddy/uk.co.nightshadearts.golfcaddy}<br>
```

Calls:

```
GolfCaddy [Android Application]    
DalvikVM[localhost:8610]    
    Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))    
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2417    
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2512    
        ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 119    
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1863    
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99    
        Looper.loop() line: 123    
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4363    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]    
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521    
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 860    
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 618    
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]    
    Thread [<13> Binder Thread #2] (Running)    
    Thread [<11> Binder Thread #1] (Running)
```

Answer:

Actually, I seem to have solved it, though I don't really know what I've fixed.

Following instructions fromn alextsc on [app won't install after package rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624324/app-wont-install-after-package-rename) I did the following:

Dumped the faulty project completely (deleted the project and the file tree) - fortunately I had the common sense to have copied the original before I did anything.

Copied the original back under 'workbench'.

Added a new project (original name) using create from existing source option.

That got it back and working.

Then rt clk on project and select Android Tools >> Rename application package, and let it do everything it wanted to.

Under src the package still had the old name, however. Used Eclipse refactor on that to change to the new name.

Still seems to work. All src files have the right package as well.

Renamed the (one) activity - still works. After that it was just more internal code modifactions line the XML app name.

Conclusion: Android Tools >> Rename application package did something, but I don't know what.

Moral: pick a name and stick to it in future.

Comment: Post your logcat calltrace and console errors please.

Comment: Won't let me add the logcat trace in a comment.

Comment: Don't put it in a comment. Edit your question and add it to the end. Please format it for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Change the package name in manifest as

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.org.xxx" // your packagename here..
    >
  </manifest>
```

after changing this R.java will created once again under the new package and then you have to import R in all activity..

Try this, it may helpful to you..

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.

In the Eclipse project "src" folder, you are going to have something called "com.test...", rename it to the new name and click OK. Then all the files should update automatically. At least it worked perfectly for me.

Please, remember that you have to change it in the Android Manifest as well.