# Old Android app name won't disappear after renaming

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing two Android apps which share most of theor code (sort of a Basic and a Pro edition).

I started with the Pro edition, giving it a package name like com.example.proapp.

For the Basic edition, I created a branch of the Pro edition in git and created a copy of the Eclipse workspace. With the Basic branch active, I opened the Basic workspace in Eclipse and:

- Changed `app_name` in `strings.xml`.
- Changed the package name in `AndroidManifest.xml`. (The `android:title` attribute for both the application and its main Activity point to `@string/app_name`.)
- Using Refactor, changed the Java package name from `com.example.pro` to `com.example.basic`.
- Replaced the app icons.

Now, when I start the app, everything looks fine. The new title and icon are there.

However, when I go into "Manage Apps" on Android, the Basic app shows up with the icon and title string of the Pro app. (If I install both, I get two entries for the Pro app; only after tapping one of them do I see which is which by looking at the package name.)

What is wrong here? How can I make my Basic app show up under its proper name and with the proper icon?

**Update:** I tried creating a second git repository from the "basic" branch and imported the code into a fresh Eclipse workspace. I uninstalled both flavors of my app from my phone and dropped in the fresh build. Behavior is still the same - the launcher and action bar show the correct icon and app title, while Manage Apps shows the "Pro" icon and title.

Where do this "undead" icon and title come from? We can now rule out the Eclipse workspace, and we can rule out build debris in the working copy.

It almost looks like Android keeps a cache of installed app data, even beyond uninstall, and resurrects app data from there. But that's just speculation... can anyone shed light on this?

Also, why does Android believe the two apks are the same app? Is there any internal identifier in the APK, besides the package name?

**Update 2:** Today I get the correct name and icon for the Basic version (the Pro one is not installed) in Manage Apps, though I haven't changed anything since I last looked. The only thing is that the Manage Apps activity probably got killed and restarted in the meantime. Seems I'm triggering a bug in Manage Apps... but what is triggering it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

After reading [Android project rename - won't launch now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481525/android-project-rename-wont-launch-now?lq=1) I did the following:

- Removed all previous versions from device
- Created a fresh branch from the Pro version
- Imported the code into a fresh Eclipse workspace
- **Renamed the package using Android Tools > Rename application package from the menu**
- Changed Java package name under `src` using Refactor
- Adapted strings and icon as necessary for Basic version
- **Cleaned project**
- Launched Basic version
- Closed Eclipse and switched back to Pro branch
- Launched Eclipse with Pro workspace
- **Cleaned project**
- Launched Pro version

And voilà! I get two different apps with different names and different icons in Manage Apps, both on my Nexus S and in the VirtualBox.

**Lessons learned:**

- **Always use Eclipse commands to rename apps or packages.** Changing strings in the manifest file is not enough. Apparently Eclipse makes some more changes than just updating the manifest, possibly in the workspace folder.
- **Clean between two builds of different branches.** Otherwise you will (evidently – I tried it) carry over debris from the past build, resulting in resources getting mixed up between branches, and end up building something totally different from what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `android:label` on your `<application>` to give a different name to the app. Also make sure you clean you project for the resource changes to appear.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo (now corrected). Both `<application>` and main Activity have `android:label="@string/app_name"`. And the weird thing is that the main activity and launcher icon have the correct title, it's just in Manage Apps that the old title still appears, though I don't see it anywhere in the code. Same goes for the icon: launcher and Activities use the correct icon while Manage Apps uses the old one, though it is definitely not in the `res/` folder structure any more. I cleaned the project a few times, to no avail...

Comment: If you have a different phone or emulator try installing there.

Comment: I tried in Android x86 on VirtualBox. There, when I install one app, it replaces the other. Something in the APKs seems to tell Android that the two packages are identical.

Comment: My experience is that the package name in many situations gets linked to the application name, especially in the android app-store. The way I solved it in the past was to make sure to use different package names for pro/lite versions respectively e.g. com.myapps.myfirstapplite and com.myapps.myfirstapppro. That way the apps will be able to co-exist one devive for instance.